# Multi-tasking and Time-sharing properties

Tags: operating-system

So I have a question which I know the answer but do understand so I will be very happy if someone could explain me.

In os system which is multi-tasking but not time-sharing which one of the following mechanism are not required:

1. context switch
2. Interrupt handler
3. Pre-emptive scheduling
4. Process Control Block (PCB)

After I [read](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20101031182605AAczoHe) and understand the mechanism I tried to answer the question and I understood it is 3.

but why ?

1.Is elementary why we need that (because it handle several programs at the same

time but we should always keep the context of each thread).

1. case I suddenly  press a key so the time- sharing need that.
2. why? why do I need that in time-sharing but not in multi tasking. I guess I do not really understand that so please give a little prespective about this.
3. save all the information regarding each process (elementary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Time Sharing we have to ensure that processor will give 'n' sec of it's processing time to every terminal in order. Thus we have to pre-empt the current terminal being processed by CPU after 'n' seconds.whereas a multitasking OS can also use co-operative multitasking method to achieve multitasking.

Answer (score 1):

Time sharing is sharing the processor time between several terminals (printers, monitors, I/O devices, etc).

You can see this type of setup in labs, offices, etc. There will be only one processor (mostly server). All the people in that lab use that server. The processor will give 'n' seconds of it's processing time to every terminal in order. Generally these processors are very fast so every terminal feels like they have their own processor.

On the other hand, Multitasking is performing several tasks at a time. Most of our pc's and laptops have multi core processors (core2, i3, i5, i7), so they have the capability to perform several tasks at a time. Each task will be performed by one of the several core processors. For example, on our laptop we can listen to music, play a movie, browse the internet, play a game, etc. etc.